# On SFMC, does OS affect UTM tags on test emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, hyperlink, tag, mac-os-x

I'm having an issue when I use SFMC on my Macbook.

When I send a test email to myself from my Mac, I can't see the UTM tags on the links. But when I switch back to my Windows PC, UTM tags on links appear on the test email.

Does anyone have any idea why might this happen? Thank you :)

Comment: I don’t see how this would be related - where and how are you checking the UTM parameters?

Comment: Yeah same here. I can check it when I move my mouse over a link or click on a link, I can see that UTM tags don't apply to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how would SFMC know which os the email sent is being viewed on? The message is built and sent